# Mesos/Marathon checkpointing and HA

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

Mesos and Marathon mention checkpointing from time to time, but I couldn't find a good explanation of how it works anywhere. Also, what does it mean in practice?

```
1) Is the Task current state continuously being stored, or is only the Task ID stored? Where is it stored and what does it contain?
2) There are two Marathon instances. Marathon has been running Nginx for a week, then goes down. Does that mean that the actual Nginx application state continues running on the second Marathon instance, or does it just restart the task from beginning? If the Task actual state is copied, isn't there a lot of data to be continuously persisted and passed around between slaves?
```

Answer (score 1):

*Slave recovery is a feature of Mesos that allows:*

- Executors/tasks to keep running when the slave process is down and
- Allows a restarted slave process to reconnect with running executors/tasks on the slave.
  ([Mesos Slave recovery](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/slave-recovery/)).

So regarding you questions this means:

1. Enough information (a little more than TaskID) is stored in order that a new slave process can reconnect to the still running executor/task.
2. As the task state is not checkpointed, it would start the task from the beginning.

Hope this helps, 
Joerg